# How to reset SSH configuration on my PC?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

How can I reset all the SSH settings, so that it worked as after fresh install? (I may delete the keys, they're not needed anymore.)

In Ubuntu 9.10, after a certain moment I started getting "Host key verification error" on every SSH server! This doesn't happen if I boot U9.10 from a USB stick.

```
culebron@culebron:~/.ssh$ ssh culebron@217.******
Host key verification failed.
culebron@culebron:~/.ssh$
```

`~/.ssh/known_hosts` doesn't exist (I must have removed it by an advice to "clean" known hosts list), yet SSH doesn't ask me, as earlier, if I want to add a host or not, just `"Host key verification failed"` every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backup ~/.ssh on your computer, rm -rf ~/.ssh, try again.  If that works, figure out which part of your old ~/.ssh was causing the problem (if you care).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the known_hosts in your ~/.ssh. Not everything. Try to paste an ssh -v output.

Comment: His question states '~/.ssh/known_hosts doesn't exist'.

Comment: whoops ;) In that case a verbose log might contain the answer.